# Copying only formats from a cell to other cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the formats from a cell into two other cells.

```
.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & SelRowNumber).Select
.Selection.Copy
.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & SelRowNumber & ":B" & SelRowNumber).Select
.Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

I don't want to use Select or Selection because it is not being considered as a best practice.

I know how to assign activesheet to an worksheet object, but I need some clarity on simplifying the other parts of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to select, just do:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("C" & SelRowNumber).Copy
    .Range("A" & SelRowNumber & ":B" & SelRowNumber).PasteSpecial ...
end with
```